# While passing an attribute typed class as a parameter to a method, is it possible to access it without setters?

Tags: java, parameter-passing

For example, let's say I have a base class:

```
package test;

public class Class1 {
    
    private int attribute1;
    private int attribute2;
    
    public Class1(int att1, int att2) {
        this.attribute1 = att1;
        this.attribute2 = att2;
    }
    
}
```

Then I'll have another class:

```
package test;
    
public class Class2 {
        
    private int attribute3;
    Class1 class1;

    public Class2(int att3){
        this.attribute3 = att3;
    }

    public void insert(Class1 class1) {
        //
    }
    
}
```

Inside the insert method, I'll be passing as a parameter an attribute of type Class1. Is it possible to access Class1 attributes without setters? if yes, how do I do it? Also:

```
package test;

public class Class2 {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        Class2 c2 = new Class2 ();
        
        c2.insert();
    }

}
```

How should I use the .insert() method? Like, what parameters? I'm a bit confused but this is how my program is supposed to go.

Comment: `Is it possible to access Class1 attributes without setters? if yes, how do I do it?` Yes. Make them public.

Comment: I can't, they're supposed to be private :/

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to access Class1 attributes without setters?

Surely you mean 'getters'. setters set the value, getters the get the value.

The answer is: No. The 2 attributes are marked `private`.

> How should I use the .insert() method?

```
Class1 c1 = new Class1();
Class2 c2 = new Class2();
c2.insert(c1);
```

Comment: Okay, so I need the getters, but inside public void insert() I'm trying to change the values of attribute1 and attribute2, that's not done with getters right?

Comment: You'd need both.